# Configuring Helidon WebClient for JsonbSupport reader, writer and media support through properties

Tags: helidon, helidon-webclient

I want to configure my helidon web-client just using config.
Something like below:
WebClient.builder()
.config(Config.create().get("web-client")).build();

and my config looks like below:

```
web-client:
  uri:<my-base-uri>
  media-support:
     services: //What should i add here which will be equivalent to below in webclient builder
```

```
                .addReader(JsonbSupport.reader())
                .addWriter(JsonbSupport.writer())
                .addMediaSupport(JsonbSupport.create())
```

I tried following config:

```
web-client:
  uri:<my-base-uri>
  media-support:
    discover-services: true
```

It worked but I guess due to default reader/writers. Still I do not understand what will discover-services exactly do and if Json support will be added automatically using above config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discover-services` property means, that Helidon will use service loader to load all `MediaSupportProviders` present on the classpath.

If you had this dependency added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.helidon.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>helidon-media-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and `discover-services` enabled, complete `Jsonb` support was found and registered automatically for you.